# Deleting numbers from a list

Tags: python

The program should generate 10 random numbers in the interval
[1;3], store them in a list, and print the contents of the list
on the screen! The user should be able to enter a number in the
interval [1;3], and the program should delete all occurrences
of this number from the list, and then print the modified list
on the screen!

I tried to run the following program with two methods, but they do not produce the final list that I wanted.

First try:

```
import random

random_list=[]
number=0
deleted_number=0
final_list=[]

for i in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,3)
    random_list.append(number)
print(random_list)
deleted_number=input('Give a number from 1 to 3, that you want to delete from the list.')
final_list = list(set(random_list) - set(deleted_number))
print('The new list without the deleted values:')
print(final_list)
```

Second try:

```
import random
random_list=[]
number=0
deleted_number=0
final_list=[]

for i in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,3)
    random_list.append(number)
print(random_list)
deleted_number=input('Give a number from 1 to 3, that you want to delete from the list.')
final_list = [item for item in random_list if item != deleted_number]
print('The new list without the deleted values:')
print(final_list)
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: " they do not produce the final list that I wanted." - maybe. We can't know, as you didn't provide the actual vs expected output. Note that, in the spirit of providing a [mre], you should start with a non-random list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the user input from a string to an int like this:

```
deleted_number = int(input('Give a number from 1 to 3, that you want to delete from the list: '))
```

and the line

```
final_list = [item for item in random_list if item != deleted_number]
```

is correct on your second try

Answer (score 1):

Use int in deleted_number

```
import random
random_list=[]
number=0
deleted_number=0
final_list=[]

for i in range(10):
    number=random.randint(1,3)
    random_list.append(number)
print(random_list)
deleted_number=int(input('Give a number from 1 to 3, that you want to delete from the list.'))
final_list = [item for item in random_list if item != deleted_number]
print('The new list without the deleted values:')
print(final_list)
```